# Adding extra classes to archive pages on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Both of the following pages use the Archive template

- http://portabellointeriors.com/product-category/sofas/
- http://portabellointeriors.com/bed-size/super-king/

Yet they display content differently as on the first example, the classes "woocommerce woocommerce-page" are added to the < body> tag

How do I tell Wordpress to add the two classes "woocommerce" and "woocommerce-page" to all archive pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theme header should have something like `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`.

You can add to your `functions.php`, or, preferably, in a [custom plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) the following filter to manipulate the classes being output:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'b5f_modify_body_classes', 10, 2 );

function b5f_modify_body_classes( $classes, $class )
{
    // Modify the array $classes to your needs
    if( is_archive() )
    {
        $classes[] = 'woocommerce';
        $classes[] = 'woocommerce-page';
    }    
    return $classes;
}
```

You can check WordPress function [`get_body_class()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post-template.php#L405) to see how it can be built.